# Quer namorar comigo? ou Quer me namorar?

Tags: verbos, verbos-transitivos

Hoje estava ouvindo algumas canções e me deparei com a seguinte música “[Quer namorar comigo?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a7INNbq_0jo)”

O verbo namorar, nesse sentido, é um verbo transitivo direto e não utiliza a preposição “com”, correto? Contudo, em uma pesquisa na “internet”, o “site” https://duvidas.dicio.com.br/namorar-ou-namorar-com/ informa o seguinte:

> Embora tradicionalmente se defenda o verbo sem preposição, a expressão *namorar com* já se encontra abonada por diversos dicionários.

Logo depois dão os exemplos abaixo, dando a entender que ambas têm o mesmo significado:

- Flávia *namora* Ricardo.
- Flávia *namora com* Ricardo.

Já no site https://veja.abril.com.br/blog/sobre-palavras/namorar-alguem-ou-namorar-com-alguem/ é informado que segundo o dicionário Aurélio:

> O uso de namorar com esta regência [namorar com] é perfeitamente legítimo, moldado em *casar com* e *noivar com*

Já pessoas como [*Vittorio Bergo*](http://www.migalhas.com.br/Gramatigalhas/10,MI86311,81042-Namorar+com), [*Francisco Fernandes*](http://www.migalhas.com.br/Gramatigalhas/10,MI86311,81042-Namorar+com) e [*Edmundo Dantès Nascimento*](http://www.migalhas.com.br/Gramatigalhas/10,MI86311,81042-Namorar+com) defendem o **não uso** da preposição *com*.

Afinal, a oração "Quer namorar comigo?" — no sentindo de ambos terem um relacionamento amoroso entre si — está correta? Passou a ser correta?

Comment: Apesar de já ter adicionado uma resposta, espero que possam responder também.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transcrevemos o registro de conceituado Dicionário de Regência Verbal: " namorar - **TD** *namorar* alguém (namorá-lo) ou **TI** : *namorar com* alguém; ser namorado. O rapaz *namora* uma estudante; *namora com* ela. Eles (se) namoram.

> OBS. A regência primitiva é de transitivo direto *- namorá-lo-*, aliás no sentido de 'inspirar amor a', evolução que é de *enamorar*.

Puristas condenam, por isso, a regência *namorar com*...(cf. Bergo:258), que no entanto é normal considerando-se os traços 'companhia, encontro' e 'conversa' (v. 'conversar' 'namorar') - uso "perfeitamente legítimo, moldado em *casar com* e *noivar com*" (Aurélio)".

<sup>*Resposta dada pela [Academia Brasileira de Letras](http://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/abl-responde)*</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Vale notar que há significados de `namorar` que não admitem a preposição. Por exemplo, o de `desejar fortemente`:

> Há dias que namoro esse vestido, mas ele é caro demais.

Uma possível explicação histórico-sociológica para a adoção da preposição `com` é o relacionamento amoroso entre pessoas não casadas ter deixado de ser tabu:

- enquanto "namorar" tem apenas o significado de `cortejar`, só o objeto direto é natural (uma pessoa dirige sua corte a alguém, não há reciprocidade implícita);
- ao passo que, ao ganhar o significado de um *relacionamento*, em que se subentende haver reciprocidade (como em "casar" ou "associar"), a preposição `com` torna-se natural também.

Comment: Acho que o fato do pessoal usar incorretamente durante tanto tempo, ajuda bastante também, mas não tinha pensado com essa visão. 

Comment: @ValdeirPsr, Sim, com certeza também tem um mero efeito de deriva aí.

Answer (score 2):

Na minha região, sudeste do Brasil, nenhuma das duas formas é usada nos dias de hoje. Ninguém mais pergunta "você quer namorar comigo/me namorar?" Hoje em dia pergunta-se:

- Você gostaria de tomar um chope comigo mais tarde?
- Eu queria te convidar pra jantar comigo no sábado.
- Você quer sair comigo?
- Tô querendo muito te ver de novo.
- Eu queria te ver no final de semana.  A gente poderia...

E  mais mil e uma outras formas de se tentar iniciar um namoro. Uma aceitação ao convite já significa, com raras exceções, um principio de namoro.  Creio que em pleno século XXI a maioria das mulheres acharia ridículo um homem chegar e perguntar "quer me namorar?".

Mas, respondendo à tua pergunta:

**As duas formas eram muito usadas no século passado e criticava-se muito o uso de "namorar" como verbo transitivo indireto, considerado incorreto. Nesse caso em particular não importa o que dita a gramática normativa. O fato é que "namorar com" já foi muitíssimo usado, para a indignação dos gramáticos prescritivos, e o uso popular consagra**.

Comment: É isto uma sessão de psicologia? ;)

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira  Não, João, é só para ilustrar o fato de que, nos dias de hoje, na região em que vivo, ninguém mais pergunta "quer me namorar" ou "quer namorar comigo?"