# Quem define o que é e o que não é português?

Tags: português-brasileiro

Existe um órgão que define a gramática, regras de colocação pronominal, o lexicom, etc da Língua Portuguesa no Brasil? Existe um documento que define isso? Um documento que informaria sobre a transitividade de cada palavra, por exemplo.

Se existirem, qual o nome da instituição e onde está tal documento?

Comment: Não existe um órgão que define as regras da gramática, mas há a [Academia Brasileira de Letras](http://www.academia.org.br/academia/fundacao), que, juntamente com outros países lusófonos, definem algumas regras da norma culta. Essas regras definem quais são as letras do alfabeto, algumas regras de grafia etc. Após isso, o presidente do país pode publicar um [decreto](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_ato2007-2010/2008/decreto/d6583.htm) tornando tais regras oficiais.

Comment: No caso de regras de transitividade, significado, pontuação etc. pode variar de gramático para gramático. Um bom exemplo disso, são as questões [Quer namorar comigo? ou Quer me namorar?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/5222/2759) e [O uso do sujeito preposicionado é válido na norma culta?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/5861/2759)

Comment: Os comentários do @ValdeirPsr formam uma boa resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Não há nenhum órgão definitivo para isso por um simples motivo: não é assim que línguas funcionam! Todo falante nativo é automaticamente fluente e 100% capaz em sua língua, é o que chamamos em lingüística de "competência lingüística". A escrita, por exemplo, é algo totalmente criado e artificial para facilitar a comunicação, há muitíssimas línguas que nem tem escrita padrão regulamentada! Os falantes apenas sabem internamente o que ocorre nas diversas camadas da língua e produzem todos os tipos de frases que necessitarem sendo totalmente compreendidos por outro também falante. Há, também, diversos dialetos, cada um com sua particularidade daí se vê tanta variação entre os ditos gramáticos prescritivistas.

Também, a língua culta é baseada sempre em dialetos com mais prestígio, tornando os outros "errados", mas que, na realidade, apenas evoluíram para caminhos diferentes.

Comment: Pensei que o trema tinha sido abolido o_O

Comment: O que mostra o quão artificial a escrita é. Eu, por exemplo, ainda o uso, pois vejo sua utilidade na representação da língua portuguesa.